# Disable/enable scroll only on Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with modal window, I want to in order to user could scroll divs in modal (when modal is open), but not all page, and if user close modal window he can scroll all page.

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
   if (!  modal ) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set body overflow property to hidden to prevent scroll. For example by adding some class to body element when popup is open:

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Compare scroll behavior with `overflow: hidden` and auto in next demo.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrceaqxn/1/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know about this solution, unfortunately in the my app, this approach works only in Chrome, FF in OSX, but in Windows 7 it does not work.. Maybe it order to I have a list which loads by scroll, I don't know, this is very strange behaviour...

Comment: My html structure http://pastebin.com/9a1wmbGe - in osx (chrome, ff) all works fine, but in windows does not work...